# Apache configuration: Access denied

Tags: apache, opensuse, zabbix

I'm pretty new to opensuse, but have experience with other distros, like arch.

I'm tring to get zabbix running but I have a problem with apache not letting me access the /zabbix subdir. I get a 403 whenever I try to access it.

This is the zabbix config file:

```
# please read how to enable zabbix frontend in
# /usr/share/doc/packages/zabbix-phpfrontend/README.SUSE
<IfDefine ZABBIX>
  Alias /zabbix "/usr/share/zabbix/"

  <Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      # Apache 2.4
      Require all granted
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
      Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
      Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
      Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      # Apache 2.2
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
      Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
      Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>

  <DirectoryMatch "/usr/share/zabbix/(conf/|include/)>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      # Apache 2.4
      Require all denied
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
    </IfModule>
  </DirectoryMatch>
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !ZABBIX>
    Redirect 403 /zabbix
</IfDefine>

php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value date.timezone Europe/Madrid
```

Any help would be nice :)

Comment: Where did you get this conf? Just follow the docs https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/installation and you will be fine. If this didnt help, post here the log.

Comment: Did you read /usr/share/doc/packages/zabbix-phpfrontend/README.SUSE and do as instructed there? What IP address are you trying to access the frontend from? If it is not in the `Allow from` list, add it there.